# how to parse string array with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift

Using `SwiftyJSON` how would I parse the following JSON array into a `Swift [String]`?

```
{
    "array": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work for me:

```
for (index: String, obj: JSON) in json["array"] {
        println(obj.stringValue)
    }
```

What would be the best way to handle this? Thank you.

Answer (score 97):

```
{
    "myArray": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

Using SwiftyJSON, you can get an array of JSON objects with:

```
var jsonArr:[JSON] = JSON["myArray"].arrayValue
```

Functional programming then makes it easy for you to convert to a [String] using the 'map' function. SwiftyJson let's you cast string type with subscript '.string'

```
var stringArr:[String] = JSON["myArray"].arrayValue.map { $0.stringValue}
```

Comment: What is that **s** inside the `map` closure?

Comment: ah sorry, I edited now, it should be '$0' that's the shorthand argument for the map closure.

.map() will iterate through every element of the json Array and assign the value to $0 each time.

Comment: Thanks. I'm facing kind of a similar issue with SwiftyJSON and arrays. I tried converting it like in your answer but it crashed with the error **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**. I posted a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28739509/1077789). If you can, can you please have a look? Thanks.

Comment: What can I do if I've something like this? [{"type":"B","rh":"+"},{"type":"0","rh":"+"}]

Comment: This will fail in runtime when received json array that contains non-string values. I suggest changing to this: `JSON["myArray"].arrayValue.map { "\($0)" }`.

Comment: What if the data was  `{
    "myArray": [ ["one", "two", 0.234],["otree", "cat", 12.454] ]
}`

Comment: Just use .stringValue instead of .string and nil or wrong type just returns an empty string. `JSON["myArray"].arrayValue.map { $0.stringValue }`

Answer (score 9):

SwiftyJSON lets you extract a `String?` using $0.string or a non optional `String` using stringValue with a default empty String value if the type doesn't match.

If you want to be sure to have an array of String with non false positives, use :

`var stringArray = self.json["array"].array?.flatMap({ $0.string })`

or in Swift 4.1

`var stringArray = self.json["array"].array?.compactMap({ $0.string })`

You can also replace `self.json["array"].array` by `self.json["array"].arrayValue` to have a `[String]` result instead of `[String]?`.

Comment: you can use flatMap to filter the strings that are equal to nil

Comment: Thanks @PabloMarrufo. Improved the reply with it and also compactMap introduced in Swift 4.1

Answer (score 5):

You have a `Dictionary` which holds an `Array` which holds `String`s. When you access a value in the `Dictionary`, it returns a simple `Array` of `String`s. You iterate it like you would any array.

```
for obj in json["array"] {
    println(obj.stringValue)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply do this:

```
for stringInArray in json["array"]{

    let value = stringInArray.1.stringValue
}
```