# NSObject does not have a member named Key error

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I need to construct a JSON object in the format shown below.

```
{
  "DeviceCredentials": {
    "UniqueId": "sample string 1"
  },
  "Handovers": [
    {
      "Occasions": [
        {
          "Id": 1
        },
        {
          "Id": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a issue though with the `Occasions` array though. The number of `Occasion` objects vary. Sometimes there can be only one Occasion, sometimes multiple. Since this is dynamic I wrote the below method to create this array.

```
func getOccasionArray(handover: Handover) -> JSON {
    var occArray = [[String: NSNumber]]()
    for occ in handover.occasions {
        let occasion = occ as Occasion
        var obj = ["Id": occasion.id!]
        occArray.append(obj)
    }
    let json = JSON(occArray)
    return json
}
```

I use the [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library to convert the created array to JSON. Here's the returned result of `json` variable looks like for a Handover which has only one Occasion.

```
[
  {
    "Id" : 243468
  }
]
```

So far so good. The problem is I'm having trouble plugging this into the bigger JSON response. Simply calling the method like this gives the error **'NSObject' does not have a member named 'Key'**.

```
var parameters = [String: NSObject]()

parameters = [
    "DeviceCredentials": [
        "UniqueId": "1212121212"
    ],
    "Handovers": [
        [
            "Occasions": getOccasionArray(handover)
        ]
    ]
]
```

I tried converting the returned value to an array `getOccasionArray(handover).arrayValue` but no change.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need SwiftyJSON here then:

Make your 'getOccasionArray' to return a [String: NSObject]

```
func getOccasionArray(handover: Handover) -> [String: NSObject] {
  var occArray = [[String: NSNumber]]()
  for occ in handover.occasions {
    let occasion = occ as Occasion
    var obj = ["Id": occasion.id!]
    occArray.append(obj)
  }
  return occArray
}
```

Define parameters as [String: NSObject]:

```
var parameters = [[String: NSObject]]()

var json: [String: NSObject] = getOccasionArray(handover)        

parameters = [["DeviceCredentials": ["UniqueId": "1212121212"], "Handovers": ["Occasions": json]]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot have the `parameters` variable's type as `JSON`. You see I need to pass this JSON object as a parameter for a URL request. I use Alamofire for HTTP request handling and it only accepts parameter in `[String: AnyObject]` format.

Comment: oh ok, it should probably work if you leave it as: [String: NSObject] as long as you change getOccasionArray to return that too. You can stay away from swiftyJSON for that case then.

I edited the post above

Comment: Thank you. That worked! Although I had to change the `getOccasionArray` method's return type to `[[String: NSObject]]` and `occArray`'s type to `[[String: NSObject]]()`. Now everything's working fine. Thank you.