# SwiftyJSON Reading JSON Array issue

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to read a json array data as below with my code but I'm getting empty result all the time while I can print the whole data. Please where would be my issue?

I've read this topic but I couldn't get the result. [Topic Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102666/how-to-parse-string-array-with-swiftyjson)

```
{"Cars":[{"Brand":"Alfa Romeo"},{"Brand":"Audi"},{"Brand":"BMW"},{"Brand":"Citroen"},{"Brand":"Dacia"},{"Brand":"Fiat"},..........
```

---

My code

```
    func getData(){

    var url = "http://test.net/services/test.php"
    var request = HTTPTask()
    request.GET(url, parameters: nil, completionHandler:
        {
            (response:HTTPResponse) in

            var jsonData = response.responseObject as! NSData
            var json = JSON(data: jsonData)

            println("All data \(json)")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                {
                    println(json["Cars"]["Brand"].stringValue)
            })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json["Cars"]` is an array, so for example to get the first item via SwiftyJSON:

```
println(json["Cars"][0]["Brand"].stringValue)
```

*In a JSON string, `{` and `}` are delimiters for dictionaries, whereas `[` and `]` are delimiters for arrays.*

**EDIT:**

Following your comment, yes, you can loop over the array:

```
if let cars = json["Cars"].array {
    for car in cars {
        println(car["Brand"])
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working now. I think I have to put it in for loop to get all values.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get your json objects using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON):

```
//Get your Data First
let json = JSON(data: data)

//Store your values from car key into Car object so we can get total count.
let Cars = json["Cars"].arrayValue

//Use For loop to get your car Brand 
for i in 0..<Cars.count
{
    println(json["Cars"][i]["Brand"].stringValue)
}
```

And your output will be:

```
Alfa Romeo
Audi
BMW
Citroen
Dacia
Fiat
```

Hope this is what you need.