# Parsing json data using swift json

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I can’t get the JSON data of message using `swiftyjson`.
When i print JSON value is there. But, when i `print(json["result"]["message"])` it is `null`

```
    {
    "result": [{

        "message": "success",
        "age": "25"

    }]
 }



let json = JSON(data:jdata)
                print(json)
                print(json["result"]["message"])
```

Comment: Looks to me as if result is an array, so you would need something like print(json["result"][0]["message"]) to access the zeroth element of the array (ie the first message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json["result"]` seems to be an array, you have to cast it to array like

```
let array = json["result"].arrayValue
let message = array[0]["message"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You `result` is of array type. And you have to set index of object.

Try:

```
var array = json["result"].arrayValue

print(array[0]["message"])
```

You can also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102666/how-to-parse-string-array-with-swiftyjson)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```swift
let json = JSON(data: jdata)

let message = json["result"].array?.first?["message"]

print(message)
```