# Swift 4.1 - Cannot convert value of type [Character] to [String]

Tags: swift, swifty-json, swift4.1

My code was supporting Swift 3.3 before, now I'm upgrading it to Swift 4.1 using Xcode 9.3. It shows me the following error while trying to build my project.

Here is code for JSON parsing

```
    // MARK: Store JSON initializer

      convenience init?(withJSON json: JSON) {
        //json mapping 
        //This is of type [Character] after mapping
        let services = json["services"].arrayValue.flatMap({ $0 }).flatMap({ $0.1.stringValue }) //Convert response to 1D array and convert it to array if String

    }
```

Here is that init method which I'm trying to call

```
//Custom init method

  init(id: Int, storeNumber: String, title: String, location: Location, type: String, zip: String, parent: Int, city: String, services: [String], state: String, storePhone: [String], pharmacyPhone: [String], pharmacyFax: [String], workingHours: WorkingHoursString) {

    //field with error
    //here self.services is of type [String]
    self.services = services
  }
```

I'm using
**pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.1.4'** For Json parsing.

> Error - Cannot convert value of type '[character]' to expected argument
>   type '[String]'

[image]

```
/* JSON for services is as given

    "services":[
     [
     "Fresh Food"
     ]
    ]

*/
    print("Services are \(services)")
    Services are ["F", "r", "e", "s", "h", " ", "F", "o", "o", "d"]
```

What could be the simplest solution to fix this?

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: I will have to build my code first, to see the JSON, as this code is of maintenance and we have just started working on this.
But I will surely post JSON object if I get it somehow.

Comment: your error in the yellow bloc shows something different from the error the compiler threw ??

Error - Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type '[character]' ...... and Cannot convert value of type '[Character]' to expected argument type '[String]'

Comment: Simple solution will be : [String(services)]. But if you know proper structure of your JSON you will not fall in this situation.

Comment: Oh extremely sorry for the mistake, and thanks for your strong observation.  Corrected it.
@PhillipJacobs

Comment: Please show your json raw output in question.

Comment: "services":[
[
"Drive-Thru Pharmacy",
"Red Box"
]
]


//The services object is as follows in JSON

Comment: So I think, expected is an array of strings, but it is producing an array of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same behavior can be observed in the following code:

```
let services: [[String: Any]?] = [
    ["service1": "service1-name"],
    ["service2": "service2-name"]
]

let result = services
    .flatMap({ $0 })
    .flatMap({ $0.1 as! String })
print(result)
```

I think this is caused by the multiple changes in `String` and `Dictionary` in Swift 4 (`String` becoming a `Collection` of characters for example). In the code above the first `flatMap` merges (flattens) the dictionaries into one dictionary and the second `flatMap` takes every value as a `String` and flattens them as a 2D `Collection` of `Character`.

I think you want something like this:

```
let result = services
    .compactMap { $0 } // remove nil dictionaries
    .flatMap { // take all dictionary values as strings and flatten them to an array
       $0.values.map { $0.stringValue }
    }
print(result)
```

This line gives an array of strings, expected results

```
let services = json["services"]
    .arrayValue
    .flatMap { $0.arrayValue }
    .map { $0.stringValue }
```

Comment: I will definitely post the JSON object, once I get it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102666/how-to-parse-string-array-with-swiftyjson
This link was also used to fix this.